# Why is a python sockets bannergraber returning errors?

Tags: sockets, banner

I have a banner grabbing script that is not returnning on some ports.

import socket

```
def banner(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((ip, int(port)))
    s.settimeout(5)
    #print(s.recv(1024)

    bytes = s.recv(1024)
    print(bytes.decode('utf-8'))


def main():
    ip = input("Please enter the IP: ")
    port = str(input("Please enter the port: "))
    banner(ip, port)

main()
```

the output is:

```
 Please enter the IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Please enter the port: 135
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonhacking/AutoRecon-Scans/bannergrabber.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonhacking/AutoRecon-Scans/bannergrabber.py", line 17, in main
    banner(ip, port)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/pythonhacking/AutoRecon-Scans/bannergrabber.py", line 10, in banner
    bytes = s.recv(1024)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Any ideas???

Comment: @Armali: The timeout is on the `recv()` call, so the connection was made successfully.

Comment: Not every protocol involves the server sending a "banner" upon successful connection. I don't know what's listening on port 135, do you?